# JS interactive fiction

Tags: javascript, game-engine

I'm trying to make a Interactive fiction game with JavaScript, the first thing on my mind is to lay down the nav system, a way for the player move from one location (room) containing a description, to another. I'm very new to JS and still learning, the code I was able to make so far simply doesn't work, really no idea why, could someone help me with this? Maybe show me another, more efficient way of doing this?

```js
node = function(desc, exits){
  this.desc = desc;
  this.exits = exits;
}

goTo = function(target){
  goTo(prompt(target[0] + ' where do you want to go? ' + target[1]))
}

/*
goTo = function(target){
  goTo(prompt(target.desc + ' where do you want to go? ' + target.exits))
}


var house = new node('this is the house desc', ['field', 'cave']);
var field = new node('this is the field desc', ['house', 'cave']);
var cave = new node('this is the cave desc', ['field', 'house']);
*/

var house = ['this is the house desc', [field, cave]]
var field = ['this is the field desc', [house, cave]]
var cave = ['this is the cave desc', [field, house]]

goTo(house);
```

The piece of code that was commented out was my attempt to do things using functions as a way of creating objects... No go...

Comment: You have infinite recursion, since `goTo` calls itself.

Comment: Your assignment to `house` refers to `field` and `cave` before you assigned those variables.

Comment: I think this may be too ambitious of a project for someone who is obviously just learning to program.

Comment: I sat down and gave it some more thought and read some other examples here on SO, and remembered the 'array of arrays' method of creating a kind of 2D map for the player to navigate. It makes way more sense than what I was trying to do before. I think I was trying so hard to make that code I wrote at first blush work, that I completely forgot that there are always more than one way to skin a cat. And you're probably right, this is a great challenge for a beginner like me. I'll keep trying though, its great exercise! And thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking more about it and searching a little bit here on OS I got to where I wanted. The code works good now and it is much simpler, I'll leave it here just in case :)

```js
var x = 1;
var y = 0;

var o = 'Nothing here'
var house = 'House description';
var field = 'Field description';
var cave = 'Cave description';

var map = [
  [o, house, o],
  [o, field, cave],
  [o, o, o],
  [o, o, o]
];

while (y <= 3 && x <= 2 && x >= 0 && y >= 0) {
  switch (prompt(map[y][x] + ' - Your current position is: ' + 'x: ' + x + ' y: ' + y)) {
    case 'n':
      y--;
      break;
    case 's':
      y++;
      break;
    case 'e':
      x++;
      break;
    case 'w':
      x--;
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks like a good way to approach it.